# Adding a 2D array to a Container class through its method .Add

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, containers

i am having trouble adding my 2D array to my container class. Help would be appreciated

This is my container class:

```
 class Container
{
    string[,] Matrix;
    public int Rows { get; private set; }
    public int Columns { get; private set; }


    public Container(int rows, int columns)
    {
        Rows = rows;
        Columns = columns;
        Matrix = new string[Rows, Columns];
    }

    public void Add(string[,] s1, int height, int width)
    {
        Matrix[Rows++, Columns++] = s1[height, width];
    }

    public string Take(int height, int width)
    {
        return Matrix[height, width];
    }
```

Error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>
> at ConsoleApp1.Container.Add(String[,] s1, Int32 height, Int32 width) in C:\Users\Justas\Desktop\Bandymas\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 26
>      at ConsoleApp1.Program.Read(Int32 n, Container Matrix) in C:\Users\Justas\Desktop\Bandymas\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 92
>      at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Justas\Desktop\Bandymas\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 45
>   Press any key to continue . . .

The error happens when I try to use my Container classes method `.Add` to add my 2D array:

```
        Matrix.Add(array, rowLength, colLength);
```

This is how the 2D array looks like:

```
string[,] array = new string[n, n];

        var list = Enumerable
        .Range(0, file.Length / n)
        .Select(i => file.Substring(i * n, n))
        .ToList();

        var res = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            char[] row = list[i].ToCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                array[i, j] = row[j].ToString();
            }
        }

        int rowLength = array.GetLength(0);
        int colLength = array.GetLength(1);
```

This is how my 2D array looks like:

```
    Berzas,su
    la;;sula;
    ;klevu sa
    ldial lap
    asula  a 
      aula, a
    r  suart 
    zemes vai
    kai du
```

It is a 9x9 array which i am trying to add to my Container

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your call to `Add()` increments rows and height, and tries to access it. By definition, it will go past the boundary set by the original construction of the array. `Arrays` in C#/.net are fixed in size.

Comment: @willaien I see,  how would i go about fixing this problem? Because i have to use a container class

Comment: Use a doubling algorithm similar to what's used inside of `List<T>`: keep track of the apparent size (rows, height) and the real size (actualrows, actualheight), then inside of the `Add()` method, use `Array.Resize()` to double the size of the underlying array every time the add operation would overflow (making sure to keep track of the new actual size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, which I am not sure, what you are trying to do is increase the 2D array, by adding an element in the diagonal of the original matrix:

For instance:

```
row = 2
column = 2


    Matrix = |'str1' | 'str2'|     s = |'str10' | 'str11' |
             |'str3' | 'str4'|         | ...    | ...    |
```

So that when `Container.Add(s,0,0)` is called, the expected results is to have

```
Matrix = |'str1' | 'str2'| empty |    
         |'str3' | 'str4'| empty |
         |empty  | empty | 'str10'|
```

This is what I understand does your code (maybe I am wrong). Then, the error appears because you are trying to access Matrix[2,2] when the Matrix array is 2x2, so there are no third column. One solution to this would be

```
public void Add(string[,] s1, int height, int width)
{
    # Create a new Array
    var newMatrix = new string[Rows++,Columns++]

    # Pass the old array to the new one
    for(i=0;i<Rows-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<Columns-1;j++)
        {
           newMatrix[i,j] = Matrix[i,j];
        }
    }

    # Add the new element
    newMatrix[Rows, Columns] = s1[height, width];

    # Then make the new matrix the good one
    Matrix = newMatrix; 
}
```

I hope this is useful, and if I am wrong, I'll make sure to change it.

EDIT:

Ok, so now I think I understand, what you want is to store the array, into the container class, not add an element. So what you should do is,

```
public void Add(string[,] s1, int height, int width)
{
    Matrix  = s1;
    Rows = height;
    Columns = width;
}
```

Maybe I have oversimplify it. Let me know

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your method but still i get the error index was out of bounds. I have updated my post with how my 2D array looks like, i don't know if doing that would be much help to people answering the question, but i'm out of ideas to be honest. What i am trying to do, is add the elements from `array` to my `Container` classes property `Matrix`, i don't want to increase the size, only to carry over the elements from my `array` to my `string[,] Matrix`

Comment: @EncoreWLT So you don't want to add a single element to the diagonal of the array? What you want is, lets say you have a 9x9 matrix in the container, to make it 18x9 after adding the array? Edit:  I see, let me modify the answer then

Comment: I dont want to make the array larger. I only want to carry over the elements from my array to my Matrix array which is located in the collection class. The Matrix array has to be 9x9 as well

Comment: I appreciate your replies. I will mark your answer as correct since i don't have the error anymore. However, how would i go about using the elements from my array with the `.Take` method in my Container class

Comment: @EncoreWLT Is alright as it is, as long as height<rows and width<columns. In your array, after adding it to the Container, you will obtain " string taker =  container.Take(0,1);" and taker would be "su". I'm not sure I am being clear here. Let's hope I am.